# Php regular expression results error

Tags: php, preg-match

I should get price from this site, here I am fetching using with PHP regular expression and cUrl.

URL = 'http://www.shopclues.com/lenovo-a526-with-1-year-physical-liquid-damage-cover-plus-insurance-refurbished.html';

```
$shopclues = get_page($url); 
if(preg_match('#<div class="price"><label>Deal Price:</label>(.*?)<\/div>#is', $shopclues,$b)) {
            $data['price'] = (float) str_replace(array(','),'',$b[1]);
        }
        elseif(preg_match('#<span id="sec_discounted_price_5713954">(.*?)<\/span><\/div>#is', $shopclues,$a))
        {
    $data['price'] = (float) str_replace(array(','),'',$a[1]);
        }
```

Comment: you can use php class DOMDocument. It is easy to impliment. for example $shopclues = get_page($url); $dom = new DOMDocument(); $dom->loadHTML($shopclues);$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div'); foreach ($nodes as $key => $node) {if ($node->getAttribute('class') == 'price') {
           // do your stuff
        }}

Comment: ok I will try but here situation is different.

Answer (score -1):

Solved by this line

```
$data['price'] = (float) str_replace(array('Rs.', ','),'',$b[1]);
```